# Would the cross section of a hypersphere be a sphere?

Tags: geometry

Would a cross section of a hypersphere be a sphere that grows toward the center of the higher dimensional object and shrinks toward its edges?

Comment: Only for a 3-sphere.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I was unclear. I was asking only about four dimensions. But that is how it would appear then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general a hypersphere in $\mathbb R^k$ is something similar to the locus of
$$ x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_k^2 = r^2 $$
for some positive $r$.

To intersect it with a $(k-1)$-dimensional hyperplane $P$, start by rotating the coordinate system such that the equation for $P$ is $x_k=H$ for some $H$ (this is always possible, by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to a normal for $P$).

If $|H|> r$, then the intersection is empty; otherwise it is the locus of
$$ x_k=H, \qquad x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_{k-1}^2 = r^2-H^2 $$
and since we're assuming $|H|\le r$, the constant term $r^2-H^2$ is positive and therefore the entire intersection is a hypersphere of radius $\sqrt{r^2-H^2}$ in the hyperplane.

Comment: I figured we'd be assuming |H|<r. |H|>r would be empty as stated.

Comment: @Jordan, whoops, that's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: I figured. Thanks, this gives me what I need.